# ActiveModel::Errors translate attribute part of error message?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, activemodel

Looking for a solution how to write translation record in I18n yml file for the following case:

```
class SomeClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate: stock_avail

  def stock_avail
    # errors is an instance of ActiveModel::Errors
    errors.add(:quantity, I18n.t('validation.stock_exceeded'))
    # how to write a translation for :quantity part ?
  end
end
```

`errors.add` is documented [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html#method-i-add).

How and where can I write translation for `:quantity` attribute of error message ?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to translate the attribute name 'quantity' or the error message? Or both?

Comment: Just `:quantity` as mentioned in the question. Translation of a message from the 2nd parameter does work trouble-free.

Answer (score 3):

If it is about the attributes names of your model, you can add translations to `config/locales/models/model_name/lang.yml`.

For example, the contents of `config/locales/models/product/nl.yml` could be something like:

```
nl:
  activerecord:
    models:
      product: Product
    attributes:
      product:
        name: Naam
        quantity: Aantal
```

Now I wonder if the custom validation message could also be stored in this file.

Also, add this to `config/application.rb`:

```
# Load locale files in nested dictionaries
config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '**', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it and report back if it did helped.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work. Precisely created path by the model name, put `:quantity` in the yml tree but without any effect.

Comment: Yup sorry, I left out an important part of this approach, the loading of the translation files. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is an addon to @zwippie's answer...

> Now I wonder if the custom validation message could also be stored in this file.

Yes, this is under `errors`/`messages` like so:

```
nl:
  activerecord:
    models:
      product: Product
  attributes:
    product:
      name: Naam
      quantity: Aantal
  errors:
    messages:
      stock_exceeded: voorraad overschreden # HERE
```

So the `error.add` would be:

```
errors.add(:quantity, :stock_exceeded)
```